# Mapping cloud (Rackspace) to the OS X desktop

Tags: macos, networking, fedora

I've got a Fedora 14 instance on Rackspace, and I'm running OS X at home.

Does anybody know how to set up and map a network drive or something that would give me access to `/var` on my home machine (other than tunneling in via the terminal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need MacFUSE, which allows you to mount "custom" filesystems in the user space. Download and install it. There are a couple of versions:

- The [original MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) is dead and I haven't seen it working under Snow Leopard at all.
- [MacFUSE Tuxera](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/System-Utilities/MacFUSE.shtml), another dead fork of the original, which still works for me, but it has some bugs.
- [Fuse4X](http://fuse4x.org/), a newer fork, haven't tried it.
- [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/), the **most recent** fork, which I use. Install the Compatibility Layer when asked for the options.

After you've installed, make sure it sits under *System Preferences*.

Then, download [Macfusion](http://macfusionapp.org/), unzip it, move to */Applications* and start the app.

Here, create a new SSHFS file system.

[image]

Enter all the necessary SSH details for your connection:

[image]

Then, click mount, and it will be mounted like a normal network drive, just using SSH.

[image]